# Export paper model with texture

Tags: export, add-on

i've just installed the add-on and on its git-hub page it's said that is also possible to export the uvs with the material both hand painted or procedural but I don't know how to do it.
Can someone please explain??
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*i've just installed the add-on*" What addon? "*on its git-hub page*" Where?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the addon is "Export paper model from blender" and here's the git-hub page (https://github.com/addam/Export-Paper-Model-from-Blender)